# strange <br> string in result of Google file diff

Tags: java, diff

The real file contains `{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "MAPBLKLOT": "1623005", "BLKLOT": "1623005", "BLOCK_NUM": "1623",`

However, there are many strange `<br>` in the result of java-Diff util, e.g. `{"type": "Feature", "properties": { "MAPBLKLOT": "1623005", "BLKLOT": "1623005"<br>, "BLOCK_NUM": "1623",`.

I don't know where the `<br>` comes from and how to fix it?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can just replace it. Be sure it's a <br> and not a \n

Comment: Perhaps the result of some pretty-printing feature - is there some setting for displayed line length or something?